# How to get .data from droppable target

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is the deal. I got some pieces inside containers and I want to be able to drag and drop pieces from one containers into another (from the view side), however in order to update my models I need target's (i.e. container where I dropped my piece) position.

Here is a short jsfiddle that demonstrates my problem: [container piece fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtxRa/19/). 
For example draw the bottom piece into the middle container. I expected to see

```
2
1
```

But got `2 2` instead. Further more I expected target to match my drop target (in this case a container).

Note: This used to work on jQuery 1.6.4 but stopped working once I moved onto 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I figured this one out myself. It was rather easy - had to change `ui.draggable.data("p_pos")` to `this.draggable.data("c_pos")` since in jQuery 1.7.1 treats dragged parameter correctly as `$(this)` in previous version I acquired that param via ui.draggable.

Here is the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtxRa/22/ that works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What is it exactly that you want to do here? Are you not looking for http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/?

You should also move your functions outside of the `$(document).ready(function(){`. There's no reason to load those after page load.

Hmm, the issue seems to be that you don't set the `pos` on `drop`. It simply doesnt get updated?

```
         drop: function(ev, ui){
             var pos = $(ev.target).data('p_pos');
             var oldpos = ui.draggable.data('p_pos');    
             console.debug(pos);
             console.debug(oldpos);
             console.debug($(ev.target));
         }
```

Comment: That is not the solution I was looking for. Besides if I pull them out of the `$(document).ready(function(){` They will do nothing since the elements they bind to don't exist yet. My problem is that I can't get `c_pos` of target container (I drag pieces into containers). My goal is to make it work. Not make it right (yet alone fast).

Comment: What is it exactly you want to actually achieve? I assume 2 elements can't be on top of each other?

Comment: Sure they can. It's a mock (i.e. unfaithful prototype). I just want to read `c_pos` from the droppable `.container` I leave my draggable `.piece` on.

Comment: I probably should have left that `ui.draggable.data('c_pos')`. It could have confused others.